# Trouble connecting to the ThingSpeak API via arduino/ESP8266

Tags: c++, arduino, client, esp8266

Im using an arduino and a wifi shield to post data to ThingSpeak. I had this working last week, but now I cant connect to the ThingSpeak API to post my data. The relevant function is:

```
void sendData(String tsData) {
  ESP8266Client client;
  client.connect(thingSpeakAddress, 80);
  delay(1000);
  Serial.print("Attempting to send data...");
  if (client.connected())
  {
    client.print("POST /update HTTP/1.1\n");
    client.print("Host: api.thingspeak.com\n");
    client.print("Connection: close\n");
    client.print("X-THINGSPEAKAPIKEY: "+writeKey+"\n");
    client.print("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\n");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.print(tsData.length());
    client.print("\n\n");
    client.println(tsData);
    lastConnectionTime = millis();

    if (client.connected())
    {
      Serial.println("Connected to ThingSpeak!");
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Sent data: ");
      Serial.println(tsData);
      Serial.print("\n");
      failedCounter = 0;
    }
    else
    {
      failedCounter++;

      Serial.println("Connection to ThingSpeak failed");   
      Serial.println();
      Serial.print("Tried to send data: ");
      Serial.println(tsData);
      Serial.print("\n");
    }
  }
  else
  {
    failedCounter++;

    Serial.println("Connection to ThingSpeak Failed");   
    Serial.println();

    lastConnectionTime = millis(); 
  }

}
```

However, I cant connect. Every time I get "Connection to ThingSpeak failed." Why cant I connect? Is there a better way to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Does your Arduino have Internet access? What if you change all `\n` to be sent to `\r\n`?

Comment: Yes, I connect to the internet and retrieve my IP easily. And I could try that, but the client.print stuff is copypasted from the Arduino tutorial.

Comment: Which error do you get, before connecting or after sending the request?

Comment: I get to the error section that includes "Tried to send data: " I believe

Comment: `client.connected()` returns false. This means your esp cannot connect to `thingSpeakAddress`